# Why are the output written to the file are zero? What are the problems of my code?

Tags: java

Ive tried input = nextLine() and append input to String data but still return null. What could be the possible problem here?

[WITHDRAW METHOD]

```
public void Withdraw(){
    
    System.out.print("Enter withdrawal amount:" );
    double withdraw = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Your withdrawal amount: " + withdraw);
        if(this.balance - withdraw < 100){
            System.out.println("The maintaining balance should not be less than 100. " );
        }else
    this.balance -= withdraw;
    System.out.println("Your new balance is:" + this.balance);
}
```

[APPEND TO FILE]

```
public void withdrawWriter(){
try{
        String data = "Your withdrawal amount: " + withdraw;

        File file = new File(this.name + ".txt");

        //if file doesnt exists, then create it
        if(!file.exists()){
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        //true = append file
        FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter(file.getName(),true);
            BufferedWriter bufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(fileWritter);
            bufferWritter.write("\r\n");
            bufferWritter.write(data);
            bufferWritter.close();

        System.out.println("Done");

    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

*Here is screenshot:*

[image: CLICK HERE FOR THE PHOTO]

Answer (score 1):

It is clear from the screen shot that you have both a local variable `double withdraw` and a field on the class `double withdraw`.

Might work if you get rid of the local, so just:

```
withdraw = input.nextDouble();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accepting input inside a local variable withdraw and trying to use instance variable inside your withdrawWriter method. Try to use instance variable withdraw while accepting input like this:

```
public void Withdraw(){

    System.out.print("Enter withdrawal amount:" );


**withdraw = input.nextDouble();**

    System.out.println("Your withdrawal amount: " + withdraw);
        if(this.balance - withdraw < 100){
            System.out.println("The maintaining balance should not be less than 100. " );
        }else
    this.balance -= withdraw;
    System.out.println("Your new balance is:" + this.balance);
}
```